# Decoding indeterminate types using JSON Decoder

Tags: swift

I'm working with a REST service that responds with indeterminate types. In particular, it can respond with a `String`, a correct payload (`T: Decodable`) or an error payload (`PayloadError`).

In order to cope with this type of requirement I've ended up with the following solution:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let either = try decoder.decode(Either<T, PayloadError>.self, from: data)
    switch either {
        case .left(let value):
            completion(.success(value))
        case .right(let payloadError):
            completion(.failure(.generic)))
    }
} catch {
    if let value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as? T {
        completion(.success(value))
    } else {
        completion(.failure(.generic))
    }
}
```

where `Either` is defined as:

```
enum Either<T, U> {
    case left(T)
    case right(U)
}

extension Either: Decodable where T: Decodable, U: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let value = try? T(from: decoder) {
            self = .left(value)
        } else if let value = try? U(from: decoder) {
            self = .right(value)
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(
                codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                debugDescription: "Cannot decode \(T.self) or \(U.self)"
            )
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think the code looks good or should I use a more elegant solution?

**Update 01.11.2020**

These are the possible use cases along side with concrete responses.

*Use Case 1*

The client calls API method `/authenticate`. The server can responds with an authentication token of type `String` or a payload error of type `PayloadError` (if the server responds with unauthorized, for example). The JSON used to decode `PayloadError` is something like:

```
{
    code: 1,
    message: "Error message here"
}
```

`PayloadError` is defined as:

```
struct PayloadError: Decodable {
    let code: Int
    let message: String
}
```

*Use Case 2*

The client calls any other method. For example, it can call `/user` that gives back the info for the current user (the auth token is passed along). A `struct User: Decodable` is decoded from the returned JSON. If there is an error, the server replies with a `PayloadError`.

Based on the above use cases, the server can respond with:

- `String`
- `T: Decodable` (like `User`)
- `PayloadError`

What I don't like is the code in `catch` since its intent is not clear.

Comment: Can you provide an example of concrete responses of the various types, and the corresponding `T` and `PayloadError` types? – I wonder how `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as? T` works if `T` is anything but `String`.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for your comment. I've added an update as you requested. Hope it's clear.

Comment: I assume that `.generic` is from your custom error type? Perhaps you can add the signature of the completion function (including the used types), just to avoid misunderstandings. – As far as I can see, there is a general problem: If a string is expected, then *any* response which is not a well-formed PayloadError will be interpreted as a string.

Comment: @MartinR sorry for the delay. I've finally end up splitting the two use cases. See below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally end up splitting the two use cases. This in order to make the code readable and more maintainable.

`PayloadError` is mapped to a `ServiceError: Error` in order to align the output.

*Use case 1*

```
guard let data = response.data else {
    completion(.failure(.invalidData))
    return
}

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let payloadError = try? jsonDecoder.decode(PayloadError.self, from: data) {
    completion(.failure(ServiceError.from(payloadError)))
} else if let token = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    completion(.success(token))
} else {
    completion(.failure(.decodingError))
}
```

*Use case 2*

```
guard let data = response.data else {
    completion(.failure(.invalidData))
    return
}
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
guard let either = try? decoder.decode(Either<T, PayloadError>.self, from: data) else {
    completion(.failure(.decodingError))
    return
}
switch either {
case .left(let value):
    completion(.success(value))
case .right(let payloadError):
    completion(.failure(ServiceError.from(payloadError)))
}
```